# convert tostring to datetime in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me please?

I need to convert this:  `20140619105204`

to this: `06/19/2014 10:52:04`

I have tried this so far:

```
CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, '20140619105204', 112), 22)
```

Comment: And the problem with your code is?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Im using sql; 

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. - this is the output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
declare @y varchar(256) = '20140619105204'
declare @x varchar(256) 

set @x = SUBSTRING(@y, 0,5) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@y, 5,2) +'-'+ SUBSTRING(@y, 7,2) +' ' 
          + SUBSTRING(@y,9,2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@y,11,2) +  ':' + SUBSTRING(@y,13,2)


SELECT CONVERT(varchar, cast(@x as datetime),22)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to parse out the different date parts. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, 
    CONVERT(datetime, left('20140619105204', 8) + ' ' + 
    SUBSTRING('20140619105204', 9, 2) + ':' + 
    SUBSTRING('20140619105204', 11, 2) + ':' + 
    SUBSTRING('20140619105204', 13, 2), 112), 22)
```

Here I have used a variable to make it a bit cleaner:

```
DECLARE @SomeDate VARCHAR(20)

SET @SomeDate = '20140619105204'

SELECT CONVERT(varchar, 
 CONVERT(datetime, left(@SomeDate, 8) + ' ' + 
 SUBSTRING(@SomeDate, 9, 2) + ':' + 
 SUBSTRING(@SomeDate, 11, 2) + ':' + 
 SUBSTRING(@SomeDate, 13, 2), 112), 22)
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e5db7/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

Your input string does not match [any recognised date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), but as you only want output as a string, you could do it with a whole bunch of calls to [`SUBSTRING(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)